# MySql select quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql

I have the fallowing code :

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "";
```

I don't know what kind of quotation marks should i use, because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "";
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes should be used:

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

None, instead you should use a placeholder and then allow the database library / server to handle the escaping and quoting of your data (as described in [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068)).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `single quotes('')`

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to construct queries. You have chosen a raw approach which is legal, but the extension your using is marked depricated. I suggest looking into `mysqli` and PDO.

For your answer.

```
$query = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` "
       . "WHERE `email` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($this->email) . "'";
```